# Second order non linear recurrence relation

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

$$  G_n= G_{n-1}+ (\frac{3}{4})^n G_{n-2}, \quad with \quad  G_0=1,G_1=1 $$

I am trying to find the limit $ \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} G_n$ which converges to $ 5.457177946$.

Or to find an upper bound of $g_n$ that still converges to a constant. Fibonacci sequence does not converges to a constant although it is an upper bound.

I do not need an exact solution, I just a tip or a method name that I could use. I tried to find the general form of the coefficients, but it seems hard to find.

Comment: you mean an explicit solution?

Comment: I suggest to modify your question and ask for the  limit value of your sequence ($\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{G_{n+1}}{G_n}$). Maybe add Fibonacci tag  is useful for your question.

Comment: I am a bit curious. Can I ask you to say about motivation of your question. Thanks.

Comment: Ran the recurrence relation on a spreadsheet. It has a limit of 5.457177946. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Amin235 This recurrence relation is an upper bound of a more complex one. In fact, my professors and I are counting some sort of increasing labeled trees :)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner an explicit solution would be great, but an upper bound would be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an exact answer but maybe useful. solving your sequence in the general case is difficult and because of this we consider the special case of your sequence as follows 
$$
G_n^{(k)}= G_{n-1}^{(k)}+ (\frac{3}{4})^k G_{n-2}^{(k)}, \quad with \quad  G_0^{(k)}=1,G_1^{(k)}=1 \tag{1}
$$
where $k$ is a natural number. By numerical computation(as mentioned) the limit value of your sequence is $5.457177946$. Now the question it is which $k$ is suitable to choose such that the special sequence $(1)$ can estimate the general case of your sequence.

The answer of choosing $k$ is depend on the maximum values that you need for $n$. At first, we can see that the solution of $(1)$, is in the following form
$$
G_n^{(k)}=\frac{ \left( -1-\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}} \right)  \left( -2\,{\frac {{3
}^{k}{4}^{-k}}{1+\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}}}} \right) ^{n}
}{\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}} \left( 1+\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}}
 \right)}+
\frac{ \left( -2\,{\frac {{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}}{1-\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}}}}
 \right) ^{n}
}{\sqrt {1+4\,{3}^{k}{4}^{-k}}}\tag{2}
$$
We denote the relation $(2)$ by $E(n,k)$. Suppose that the maximum value that you need for $n$ is $1000000$ that means you work with $n\leq 10^6$. In continue, you should find the minimum $k$ such that holds in the following relation 
$$
E(10^6,k)\leq 5.457177946 \tag{3}
$$
the solution of $(3)$ is $k=44$ that means the following sequence 
$$
G_n^{(44)}= G_{n-1}^{(44)}+ (\frac{3}{4})^{44} G_{n-2}^{(44)}, \quad with \quad  G_0^{(44)}=1,G_1^{(44)}=1 \tag{1}
$$
is estimate the general case of your sequence for the first $10^6$ elements of the general case with minimum error.

I hope, it be useful.

Comment: Actually, your heuristics can be made into a precise estimate in the following way. For $n \ge 0$,  we have that $G_{n+k} = G_{n+k-1} + (3/4)^{n+k} G_{n-2} \le G_{n-1} + (3/4)^k G_{n-2}$. By a known theorem, we have that $G_{n+k} \le G_n^{(k)}$ where the latter has starting values $G_0^{(k)} = G_k$ and $G_1^{(k)} = G_{k+1}$. The general formula for $G_n^{(k)}$ can be found for arbitrary starting values. Taking the limit for $n$ that goes to $\infty$, one gets an upper bound for the limit of $G$ in terms of $G_k, G_{k+1}$ (eg one can take $k=44$ as per your example)